# How alibaba-cloud extend /dev/vda?

Tags: linux, alibaba-cloud

I extend my ESC server recently, and I have a question about how alibaba-cloud extends my /dev/vda from 50GiB to 100GiB, I even no need to shut down my cloud server.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend a disk volume and partition without giving a restart. It is called extend disk online.

Step 1.  Check whether the kernel version is 3.6.0 or later as only 3.6.0 or later are supported for this operation.

```
uname -a
```

Step 2. Create a disk snapshot as a backup.

Step 3. Operate in the ECS console as follows:

- Log on to the ECS console.
- In the left-side navigation pane, choose Storage & Snapshots > Disks.
- In the top navigation bar, select a region.
- Find the disk to be extended and choose More > Resize Disk in the
  Actions column.

[image: Extent disk online]

- Select Resize Online in the Resizing Method column.
- Specify the capacity after resizing.
- Confirm the fees, read and select ECS Service Terms, and then click
  Resize.

Your system disk is extended.

Step 4. Now you need to [Resize partitions and file systems of Linux system disks](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/111738.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.879954.22.1d9414510xbpRc#concept-ocb-htw-dhb)